# Can this marriage be nullified like this?

Tags: halal-haram, nikah, religion, interfaith-marriage

Im 24 years old male. Earning well, and Alhamdullilah have long term’s established to continue this InshAllah. However 5 years back i liked a girl at my college whol i was interested in. I talked to my parents and hers and things did not go well. I was told to earn a degree and present my self. However in the meanwhile by the girl herself and as per her parents intentions they would forcefully marry her off to someone living well off due to which, we did a court marriage.
Once that was done we disclosed it to our parents. My parents were ready to accept it however there were reservations from the other side. In order to overcome that. I continued pursuing my degree as well as to prove myself better i started working at my father in laws office. For a straight year i worked there without a pay and in order to give time better here i closed up my other business and my father in law putting me as a puppet to deal with the business matters went away with all the family members including my wife to Canada.
And now he says that i can’t do anything about it. And he will go ends meet to nullify this marriage.

Should i run away to canada grab my wife and be back? Theres gonna be war ahead once i come back to pakistan and if i stay abroad longer my family back at pakistan can get in trouble too..

Comment: You said "For a straight year i worked there without a pay and  ..." And so, now what would you expect from those slaveholders? If you have a wife, you should (excuse my crude speech) "have the balls" to protect her. This opinion is not based on Islam.